# How do SQLAllocHandle defined?

Tags: c++, winapi, odbc

ALL,

I have a following code:

```
    SQLHENV env;
    typedef SQLRETURN (*SQLALLOCINFO)(SQLSMALLINT, SQLHANDLE, SQLHANDLE *);
    SQLALLOCINFO *sqlAllocInfo = NULL;
    HINSTANCE hInst = ::LoadLibrarh( TEXT( "odbc32" ) );
    sqlAllocInfo = (SQLALLOCINFO *)lib.GetSymbol( "SQLAllocHandle" );
    if( sqlAllocInfo )
        sqlAllocInfo( SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HENV, &env );
```

trying to execute this code I'm getting following error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.
This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a
function pointer declared with a different calling convention.
```

So now my question is: how is the function declared?

Thank you.

P.S.: Trying to build an execute with MSVC 2010 on Windows 8. The program is build with Unicode support.

Comment: Side note: you may want to add language tag and figure out/update post with  what calling convention your code uses.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Language added and the post updated. Please let me know if that update is not enough.

Comment: Looks fine to me now. It's really should not be too hard to just try all calling conventions so :)  (no, I don't know answer).

Comment: Most Microsoft stuff uses __stdcall. Btw `LoadLibrarh` is not a real function, you really should show real code whenever possible.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, I tried to add it like this: typedef SQLRETURN __stdcall (*SQLALLOCINFO)(SQLSMALLINT, SQLHANDLE, SQLHANDLE *); but got the error: "a calling convention may not be followed by a nested declarator". Same error I get if using SQL_API.

Comment: Try `typedef SQLRETURN (__stdcall* SQLALLOCINFO)(SQLSMALLINT, SQLHANDLE, SQLHANDLE*);`

Comment: Also when you use that typedef, don't declare it as a pointer. E.g. `SQLALLOCINFO sqlAllocInfo = (SQLALLOCINFO)GetProcAddress(...)`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, that worked. Thank you.